# Get Value selected combobox dynamic data in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, combobox

i have a combobox that list a dynamic data from database, i use javascript, and it's works. but the problem is how to get the selected value ? i want to get value of "pilih rayon". this is the picture and code.

[image: this is the picture]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showcabang(){
    <?php
    require ('config.php');
    $query = "SELECT distinct org_id FROM gis";
    $cabang = pg_query($query);

    while ($data = pg_fetch_array($cabang))
     {
       $idcabang = $data['org_id'];

       // membuat IF untuk masing-masing propinsi
       echo "if (document.list.cabang.value == \"".$idcabang."\")";
       echo "{";

       // membuat option kabupaten untuk masing-masing propinsi
       $query2 = "SELECT distinct cp_rayon_name FROM gis WHERE org_id = $idcabang ORDER BY cp_rayon_name";
       $hasil = pg_query($query2);
       $content = "document.getElementById('rayon').innerHTML = \"<select name='rayon'>";
       while ($data2 = pg_fetch_array($hasil))
       {
           $content .= "<option value='".$data2['cp_rayon_code']."'>".$data2['cp_rayon_name']."</option>";
       }
       $content .= "</select>\";";
       echo $content;
       echo "}\n";
     }

    ?>

    }
    </script>
```

---

```
<html>
    <form name="list"  method="post"  action="json.php">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Pilih ID Cabang</td><td>:</td>
          <td>
              <select name="cabang" onchange="showcabang()">
              <option>Silakan Pilih</option>
              <option>------------------------</option>
              <?php
                     // query untuk menampilkan propinsi
                     $query = "SELECT distinct org_id FROM gis ORDER BY org_id";
                     $hasil = pg_query($query);
                     while ($data = pg_fetch_array($hasil))
                     {
                        echo "<option value='".$data['org_id']."'>".$data['org_id']."             </option>";
                     }
              ?>
              </select>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Pilih rayon</td><td>:</td>
          <td>

          <select name="namarayon" id="rayon"></select>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: selected value on the client side or the server side?

Comment: The way you have try to solve this problem is very messy, i suggest to read about `JSON` `jquery` so you can have some cleaner code.

Comment: on server side, example : i want to get the value and show that in other page.

Comment: PHP != javascript...  in the script tag you need code in javascript not in PHP... read about [client-server php model](http://tut.php-quake.net/en/communication.html) ... in javascript use document.getElementByName("namarayon").value

Comment: i know that php != javascipt, but how can we get that value? after submit,  in json.php i try to get the value but fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your json.php file when the form has been submmited you can consume your data by using `$_POST['cabang'] and $_POST['namarayon'].`

Comment: yeah i know, in general case it's must be works, but no at this case. on 'cabang' it's works, but no at 'namarayon'. i don't know why. there is something in my code ? please, i'm still newbie.